# Mysql Error doesn't establish connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection, join

I have a joint table query but keep getting errors as below:

I have also recreated the database again but still getting same error. Checked my connection to mysql and works fine - is there anything wrong in my joint table query?

```
$select_quote=mysql_query("SELECT authors.name, authors.id, authors.img, authors.slug, quotes.author_id, quotes.title, quotes.id, quotes.meta_keys, quotes.meta_description, quotes.slug, quotes.content
                           from quotes, authors
                           WHERE quotes.author_id = authors.id
                       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_quote)) {

    $author_id = $row['authors.id'];
    $author_name = $row['authors.name'];
    $author_slug = $row['authors.slug'];

    echo" $author_slug";
    }
```

This is my connection

```
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');
$user_name = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "quotes";
$server = "localhost";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
if ($db_found) {
 echo "Working";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
}
```

These are the errors I am getting

> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 11

Could you please advice me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` you may get a "deprecated" error message. That's been known to happen lately. You haven't shown us how you're connecting also. Do, and replace credentials with `xxx`

Comment: Also make sure your DB connection isn't `mysqli_` based. `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions do not mix. So, show us your full code including DB connection.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, you should be implementing mysqli or PDO

Comment: Thank you both, I've added my connection as well

Comment: Both tables are in the same database?

Comment: You're closing your DB with `mysql_close($db_handle);` (you're telling it, if found then close connection) remove it or place it after successful query. @user3482036

Comment: great, that erorr is gone but I get these notices <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: authors.id in <b>/home/user/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: authors.name in <b>/home/user/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: authors.slug in <b>/home/user/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />

Comment: Instead of `$author_id = $row['authors.id'];` try `$author_id = $row['id'];` and do the same for the rest and see what that gives.

Comment: it works but how would i know which id or slug im getting?

Comment: That, I couldn't tell you. I'm not very good at those types of queries when using more than one table. Something I really do need to work on lol

Comment: You're welcome. So, problem solved or would you rather someone else submits an actual "answer"?

Comment: solved, i just opened another post for this, lets see what happens

Comment: Then we should close this question. People may not like it (you asking the same question from the same codes). Let me put one in then for this question. They might close it because of a probable duplicate.

Comment: I posted an answer below to close the question. If you don't want to accept it since it did solve this problem, then delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

(To close this question)

You're closing your DB with `mysql_close($db_handle);` (you're telling it, if found then close DB connection) remove it or place it after successful query.

Plus, instead of `$author_id = $row['authors.id'];` do `$author_id = $row['id'];` and do the same for the rest.

---

Disclaimer: You should also consider switching to `mysqli_` or PDO. `mysql_` are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.